# Why is rails dumping data to the page on each

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a simple controller called list_controller with an index that basically does

```
def index
    @lists = List.all
end
```

Then i have a view called index.html.haml that looks like:

```
%h1 My lists
= @lists.each do |list|
    .row-fluid
        %h2= list.title
        %p= list.description
%hr
= link_to "New list", new_list_url
```

This works and renders but at the bottom of my list is what appears to be a ruby print of the lists objects, in this case a nice big ugly:

```
[#<List id: 1, title: "Petes todo list", description: "This is petes main list, all sorts of good stuff", created_at: "2012-03-26 21:42:57", updated_at: "2012-03-26 21:42:57">, #<List id: 2, title: "Petes work list", description: "A list for petes work stuff", created_at: "2012-03-26 22:09:50", updated_at: "2012-03-26 22:09:50">]
```

Why is this happening? How can I stop it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're outputting the result of the `each`, change:

```
= @lists.each do |list|
```

to:

```
- @lists.each do |list|
```

---

Haml documentation: [`=`](http://haml-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.HAML_REFERENCE.html#inserting_ruby_) vs [`-`](http://haml-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.HAML_REFERENCE.html#running_ruby_)

Answer (score 1):

`= @lists.each do |list|` tells Haml to evaluate Ruby code to the right and then print out the return value. You should rewrite your view to

```
%h1 My lists
- @lists.each do |list|
    .row-fluid
        %h2= list.title
        %p= list.description
%hr
= link_to "New list", new_list_url
```